# Constrain numpy to automatically convert integers to floating-point numbers (python 3.7)

Tags: numpy, floating-point, int, dtype

I have just made the following mistake:

```
a = np.array([0,3,2, 1]) 
a[0] = .001
```

I was expecting 0 to be replaced by .001 (and the dtype of my numpy array to automatically switch from int to float). However, print (a) returns:

```
array([0, 3, 2, 1])
```

1. Can somebody explain why numpy is doing that? I am confused because multiplying my array of integers by a floating point number will automatically change dtype to float:

> ```
> b = a*.1
> print (b)
> array([0. , 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])
> ```

2. Is there a way to constrain numpy to systematically treat integers as floating-point numbers, in order to prevent this (and without systematically converting my numpy arrays in the first place using .astype(float)?

Comment: In assignment, `a[i]=b` `b` is cast to match `a`. `a` dtype cannot be changed (inplace). In the big picture it's safer that way.  Your `b` is a new array.

Comment: `a = np.array([1,2,3], float)` is the closest to automatic float array notation.

Answer (score 0):

First lets look at the following two rules. These are defined for python :

1. In assignment, x[0]=y , y is cast to dtype of x and the dtype of x is not changed.
2. In case of multiplication of float and int results in a float. `enter code here
3. In assignment, x = y , x is cast to dtype of y.

When you do `a = np.array([0,3,2, 1])  a[0] = .001`

since a[0] is int, by rule 1, dtype of a[0] (and also a) remains unchanged.

While in case of `b = a*.1 print (b) array([0. , 0.3, 0.2, 0.1])`

By rule 2, the result of a*.1 is of dtype float (ie dtype(int * float) = float). and by rule 3, b is cast to type float

As  @hpaulj mentioned, "a = np.array([1,2,3], float) is the closest to automatic float array notation. – hpaulj 18 hours ago". But ya, this is essentially the same as having to use .astype(float)

I cannot understand the need for a separate way that you require. Can you further detail why you'd like a way other than using .astype(float)?