# Python: Change a float array element to an integer value, but python outputs the integer value in float format

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a python numpy array:
y = np.array([5.2,1]) . Now I want to change y[0] to 1:
y[0] = 1

But Python output is:
array([1., 1.])

Somehow it writes the integer values in float format, which is what I don't want. I want the output is : array([1, 1]).
How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: how did you change the type of the array?

Comment: `y.astype(int)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969789/constrain-numpy-to-automatically-convert-integers-to-floating-point-numbers-pyt

This might answer your question

Comment: `x=y.astype(int)`.  Look at `x` not `y`.